# how to break multiple if statements in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to break the execution when it matches 
particular condition. Have tried break,goto and did not work.Please advise.

```
if (condition 1){
   print("1");
}
if (condition 2){
   print("2");
}
if (condition 3){
   print("3");
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use `else if` if conditions are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Is the JavaScript `switch` construct an option? http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: why not use `if - else if - else`?

Comment: break the execution of ... what? a function? a loop? be specific.

Comment: I want to print and come out of a function , else if , Switch does not fit my usecase.

Comment: @techq - my solution below will allow you to do that functionally-- however, please note that it is effectively the same thing as using an `if...else` or `switch` statement-- the function could be rewritten using either of those constructs and the outcome would be the same.

Answer (score 2):

I am highly confused by your assertion that `switch` and `else...if` do "not fit [your] use case"-- those are the **constructs Javascript provides explicitly for the case you are seeking**-- evaluating a series of conditions and breaking when one is matched.  By this measure, Lahiru Ashan's answer is a valid one, and the comments on your question are also valid solutions.

The only other means I can think of, if for some ***bizarre*** reason you truly cannot use an `if..else` or a `switch` in your code, would be to place all the conditionals in a function, and use a `return` statement to short circuit and exit the function when you are complete.  Something like this:

```
function evaluateInput(inputVal) {
    if (inputVal === 1){
       print("1");
       return;
    }
    if (inputVal === 2){
       print("2");
       return;
    }
    if (inputVal === 3){
       print("3");
       return;
    }
}

x = 3
evaluateInput(x);
```

However, I really think you need to revisit the other potential solutions, as they are valid and far more conventional means to achieve what you seek.  The `if..else` solution is simple and straightforward:

```
    x = 3
    if (x === 1){
       print("1");
    } else if (x === 2){
       print("2");
    } else if (x === 3){
       print("3");
    }
```

If you have a long chain of conditions to evaluate and this looks like too much overhead, then the [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement is an excellent alternative, in which case Lahiru Ashan's solution is a valid contender.

It is my suspicion that the `if..else` or `switch` should be valid for your scenario-- if they are not, perhaps you should explain more clearly *why* they are not, with examples in code, to help the StackOverflow community evaluate your issue and help you arrive at a solution.

Answer (score 0):

try using `switch`,

```
var x = 3;

switch(x){
  case 1:{
   alert('one');
   break;
  }
 case 2:{
  alert('two');
  break;
 }
 case 3:{
  alert('three');
  break;
 }
 case 4:{
  alert('four');
  break;
 }
}
```